# Divide data based on matching first 14 characters in column name

Tags: r, subset

I want to divide my dataset into subsets, based on matching the first 14 characters. Each column name contains a unique number, so I don’t want to group them by the entire column name.

There are 75 different species, so I want to avoid having to specify the name of each, but use a general expression.

Example dataset is

```
pharomachrus_auriceps_136959<-c(10,30,11,12)
pharomachrus_auriceps_136675<-c(11,12,13,12)

trogon_personatus_100722<-c(12,14,15,13)
trogon_personatus_100766<-c(18,19,17,16)

new.spec<-cbind(pharomachrus_auriceps_136675, pharomachrus_auriceps_136959, trogon_personatus_100722, trogon_personatus_100766)
```

I tried this

```
v <- unique(substr(names(new.specs), 0, 14))
subdata<-apply(v, function(x) select_(new.specs, ~matches(x)))
```

but it will give me a list, and I need a data frame.

I thought perhaps I could use split with this somehow, but

```
subdata <- split(new.specs,v)
```

was clearly a naive thought.

What is the best way of doing this, to avoid having to type out all 75 species names?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify how you want your data.frame to be formatted after splitting the columns?

Comment: I need a separate data.frame for each species, so one for all columns containing pharomachrus and one for trogon in the example. Could be separate objects under the species names or a list of dataframes. Ideally I'd want the first column of the entire data set to be copied as first column for each subset.

Comment: It's generally easier to subset and filter data like this when the variable names (species in this case) are in one column, the values in another (_i.e._ "long", not "wide" format). Is there some requirement _e.g._ a software tool which requires that species names be column headers?

Comment: Right, I can see that. I should have taken more care explaining this. So the first column is "wavelength", ranges 300-700, then columns for each species with measures of plumage refelctance for each wavelength. The structure will make more sense explained this way I hope.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can be helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)
 new.spec %>%
      as.tibble() %>%
      gather() %>%
      mutate(species = gsub("_\\d+", "", key)) %>%
      split(., .[,'species'])

#output:
$pharomachrus_auriceps
# A tibble: 8 x 3
                           key value               species
                         <chr> <dbl>                 <chr>
1 pharomachrus_auriceps_136675    11 pharomachrus_auriceps
2 pharomachrus_auriceps_136675    12 pharomachrus_auriceps
3 pharomachrus_auriceps_136675    13 pharomachrus_auriceps
4 pharomachrus_auriceps_136675    12 pharomachrus_auriceps
5 pharomachrus_auriceps_136959    10 pharomachrus_auriceps
6 pharomachrus_auriceps_136959    30 pharomachrus_auriceps
7 pharomachrus_auriceps_136959    11 pharomachrus_auriceps
8 pharomachrus_auriceps_136959    12 pharomachrus_auriceps

$trogon_personatus
# A tibble: 8 x 3
                       key value           species
                     <chr> <dbl>             <chr>
1 trogon_personatus_100722    12 trogon_personatus
2 trogon_personatus_100722    14 trogon_personatus
3 trogon_personatus_100722    15 trogon_personatus
4 trogon_personatus_100722    13 trogon_personatus
5 trogon_personatus_100766    18 trogon_personatus
6 trogon_personatus_100766    19 trogon_personatus
7 trogon_personatus_100766    17 trogon_personatus
8 trogon_personatus_100766    16 trogon_personatus
```

Or if wide format is needed:

```
new.spec %>%
  as.tibble() %>%
  mutate(row = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -row) %>%
  mutate(species = gsub("_\\d+", "", key)) %>%
  split(.[['species']]) %>%
  map(function(x) spread(x, 2, 3) %>%select(-row, - species))

 #output:
$pharomachrus_auriceps
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  pharomachrus_auriceps_136675 pharomachrus_auriceps_136959
*                        <dbl>                        <dbl>
1                           11                           10
2                           12                           30
3                           13                           11
4                           12                           12

$trogon_personatus
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  trogon_personatus_100722 trogon_personatus_100766
*                    <dbl>                    <dbl>
1                       12                       18
2                       14                       19
3                       15                       17
4                       13                       16
```